# CodeceptJS Multiremote not working with WebdriverIO helper

Tags: codeception, webdriver-io, codeceptjs

I'm trying to automate test cases for a websocket based chat app and the Multiremote function of Codeceptjs with the WebdriverIO helper, called my attention. However, I'm struggling to make it work.

I would like to set my codecept.js config file and test files correctly to switch and act back and forth between one browser and the other one.

`{
    "output": "./output",
    "helpers": {
        "WebDriverIO": {
            "url": "localhost",
            "browser":"chrome",
            "multiremote": {
                "MyChrome1": {
                    "desiredCapabilities": {
                        "browserName": "chrome"
                    }
                },
                "MyChrome2": {
                    "desiredCapabilities": {
                        "browserName": "chrome"
                    }
                }
            },
            "restart": false,
            "windowSize": "maximize",
            "timeouts": {
                "script": 60000,
                "page load": 10000,
                "implicit": 5000
            }
        }
    },
    "include": {
        "I": "./steps/ICustom_steps.js",
        "loginPage": "./page_objects/login_page/login_page.js",
        "chatPage": "./page_objects/chat_page/chat_page.js"
    },
    "mocha": {},
    "bootstrap": false,
    "teardown": null,
    "hooks": [],
    "tests": "./test_cases/*_test.js",
    "timeout": 10000,
    "name": "chat app test"
}`

I can see the 2 browsers popping up but how can I set the test files correctly to switch interact back and forth between one browser and the other one.

Answer (score 1):

I've just figured out that it can be introduced in a helper method that calls the WebDriverIO helper. For instance,

```
useBrowserAs() {
    let client = this.helpers['WebDriverIO'].browser;
    let browser1 = client.select('browser1');
    ...INSERT YOUR WEBDRIVER IO ACTION HERE FOR BROWSER 1
    let browser2 = client.select('browser2');
    ...INSERT YOUR WEBDRIVER IO ACTION HERE FOR BROWSER 2
}
```

after that, it can be introduced in the I actor.